# Converting an byte array into 2 unsigned long in C and Delphi

Tags: c, delphi

The following C code:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

byte temp[8] = {...};

unsigned long iONE = 0;
unsigned long iTWO = 0;

memcpy(((byte *)&iONE)+sizeof(unsigned long)-4, temp, 4);
memcpy(((byte *)&iTWO)+sizeof(unsigned long)-4, temp+4, 4);
```

What is the significance of `+sizeof(unsigned long)-4`?

Could the `memcpy` statements be written as:

```
memcpy((byte *)&iONE, temp, 4);
memcpy((byte *)&iTWO, temp+4, 4);
```

And is the Delphi conversion valid:

```
var
  temp: array[0..7] of Byte;
  iONE: Cardinal;
  iTWO: Cardinal;
begin
  temp := ...;
  iONE := 0;
  iTWO := 0;

  CopyMemory(iOne, temp[0], SizeOf(Cardinal));
  CopyMemory(iTwo, temp[4], SizeOf(Cardinal));
end;
```

Comment: Ask yourself what this does on a platform where `sizeof(unsigned long)` is *greater* than 4 octets (think *8*, then do the math). You may also consider the ramifications of running this on a big-vs-little [endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) system.

Comment: Let's get serious. This is horrible, non portable code, and it's not possible to tell without context, what _"the significance"_ of those operations should be. The code seems to make assumptions about endianess and `sizeof(unsigned long)`, that at least I am not able to decipher in purpose.

Comment: It is little endian system (Windows). And the unsigned long is 4 bytes.  Not sure if I answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(byte *)&iONE)+sizeof(unsigned long)-4
```

is trying read 4 bytes from `iONE` but also account for the possibility that `unsigned long` is larger than 4 bytes. The code does so by picking off the last 4 bytes of `iONE`. Since the code always reads from the same end of the variable its behaviour varies between little and big endian machines. Without any context it is hard to say what this code is trying to achieve but my guess is that it was originally running on a big endian system with 8 byte `unsigned long`. Perhaps you know more.

In Delphi you'd probably write it like this.

```
var
  temp: array[0..7] of Byte;
  iONE: Cardinal;
  iTWO: Cardinal;
begin
  temp := ...;
  iONE := PCardinal(@temp[0])^;
  iTWO := PCardinal(@temp[4])^;;
end;
```

However, it would help to know more about the original code. Personally if I was faced with this task I'd write the code from scratch rather than make a literal port. The original code already looks poor and once it has been translated it will be even worse. Work out what the code does and write a new program using the idiom of the target language.

Two minor points on your code:

1. It is pointless to initialise a variable that is immediately over-written. That just confuses the future reader.
2. `CopyMemory` is a Windows API function and as such not portable. `System.Move` is the function to use for raw memory copies.

Comment: Your comment very useful. Thank you for the succinct Delphi code.

Comment: I deleted the post to avoid straying. Will post as new question at the right time. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: What about this question?

Comment: Thank you David. The C code is likely not original. The intended unsigned long is 4 bytes (Windows). The temp[8] is big endian, and holds IBM doubles that needs to be converted into IEEE double (little endian).  iONE and iTWO are bytes swapped before further manipulation.

Comment: I mean, I think this question has been answered

Comment: I think the question has being answered.  I forgot to add in my previous comment that the '+sizeof(unsigned long)-4' is not necessary in this case. Thank you David.

Answer (score 0):

```
memcpy(((byte *)&iONE)+sizeof(unsigned long)-4, temp, 4);
```

is copying 4 bytes from `temp` into `iONE`'s address at offset `sizeof(unsigned long)-4`, and

```
memcpy((byte *)&iONE, temp, 4);
```

will copy 4 bytes from `temp` at the beginning of the address where `iONE` is stored.

**So `sizeof(unsigned long)-4` is just an offset in bytes, at which to copy the 4 bytes from `temp`.**

Comment: While this is technically correct, that doesn't tell anything about _the significance_ :-P ...

Comment: Your comment helpful. Thank you.